# Rx (RxJS) Url Builder

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I'm looking for a good way to build urlStream using RxJS that takes multiple parameters.

```
var searchStream = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
var pageStream = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);

var urlStream = new Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
  //What goes here?
  //Should output something like http://apiurl.com?page=page&search=search
});
```

My instinct is to use `Rx.Observable.merge(searchStream, pageStream);` but after you do that you don't know which one is which parameter.

With the searchStream subject it allows me to use the subject multiple places in application to `searchStream.onNext("my search")` and have it trigger a refersh of the data. I've seen plenty of examples that use one url parameter but have yet to see an example that using multiple input streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var searchStream = ...
var pageStream = ...

var urlStream = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(searchStream, pageStream, (search, page) => {
  return baseUrl + `?search=${search}&page=${page}`;
})
.shareReplay(1);
```

I would suggest that you not use `Subject`s directly when creating streams. Likely whatever is triggering the parameter change could just as easily be wrapped in an `Observable` instead.

For instance your search would likely be attached to some text box whose change event could be wrapped in a `fromEvent`

```
//This would create a stream that waits until the user has stopped
//typing for half a second before sending a request to update.
var searchStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($textbox, 'keyup')
    .map(e => e.target.value)
    .debounce(500);
```

Comment: Did you mean those to be template literals instead of strings?